# How to make a standard preamble into a package

Tags: packages, preamble

I have a preamble that I copy and paste into nearly all of my documents. Is there a nice way to turn this into a package than I can use? I would prefer to do this in a way that doesn't depend on my Latex front end or compiler, so I can just `\usepackage{coolpreamble}`. This would also be useful for distributing to others to keep a standard LaTeX format amongst my research group.

Comment: See now also [@Qrrbrbirlbel’s answer to “Is there a source function/capability in LaTeX”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80441/80442).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can put your preamble code into a `.sty` file and then use `\usepackage{mystyle}` to load it.  Your `.sty` file will look like this:

```
% Declare that this style file requires at least LaTeX version 2e.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

% Provide the name of your page, the date it was last updated, and a comment about what it's used for
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}[2010/07/28 BBischof's custom LaTeX style]

% Now paste your code from the preamble here

% Finally, we'll use \endinput to indicate that LaTeX can stop reading this file. LaTeX will ignore anything after this line.
\endinput
```

Note that style files can get much more complicated (if you want to include options like `\usepackage[option]{mystyle}`, etc.), but this basic format should get you started.

Save your file as `mystyle.sty` and put it in the current directory with your `.tex` file.

You can also take a look at the [LaTeX2e for class and package writers](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf) guide which also available on [ctan](https://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide).  It'll walk you through this in more detail.

Comment: I suggest you use `\RequirePackage` instead of `\usepackage` while inside the the package, that will prevent problems with double inclusions and such.

Comment: Good point, Giel.  When you move the code from the preamble of your document to the style file, you can change all of the `\usepackage` commands to `\RequirePackage` (and leave the package name and options the same).

Comment: @Giel: Actually `\RequirePackage` and `\usepackage` have the same definition most of the time. Before `\documentclass` the `\usepackage` is defined to be an error message (like *package loaded before class*), but is then defined to be like `\RequirePackage`. But you are right, people should use `\ReuqirePackage` inside packages and classes.

Answer (score 47):

I’d say: don’t. There’s a plethora of `thesis.sty` packages on the web and I think they all miss one important point:

This is what classes are there for, not packages. So if you find yourself reusing the same preamble, chances are it’s for the same kind of documents. In that case, don’t make a package out of it – make a class.

The differences are minimal:

- You need to call your file `<foo>.cls` instead of `<foo>.sty`
- You (most probably) need to load a base class inside your class using `\LoadClass`
- You load the class via `\documentclass` at the beginning of your documents, instead of using `\usepackage`.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it was directly the answer to my question. However, this answer was very helpful to me and I think I will take your advice. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Konrad: wouldn't `\LoadClass` be better?

Comment: @Bruno: Better than `\documentclass`? Why?

Comment: @Konrad: I am just blindly following pp.9--10 of `clsguide.pdf`... But come to think about it, I don't know the difference.

Comment: @Konrad: here it is: run pdflatex with no input file, and as your first input type `\show\documentclass`. This will show `\documentclass=macro:->\let \documentclass \@twoclasseserror \if@compatibility \else \let \usepackage \RequirePackage \fi \@fileswithoptions \@clsextension.` In other words, the first occurrence of `\documentclass` redefines `\documentclass` to produce an error.

Comment: @Bruno. Ah. Well, see my second point. *Inside* a class you use `LoadClass` to load another class (a base class, heh) but inside the actual document, you use `documentclass`. Rule of thumb: macros starting with an upper-case letter are reserved for package writers and shouldn’t (rather, don’t need to be) used in normal documents. But to make matters worse, some package authors deviate from this rule.

Comment: @Konrad: apologies, I read too quickly, and only saw the mention of `\documentclass`. Your post is correct. --- as for your point about capitalization of macro names, I have commited this sin in a package of mine (100\% of the user commands are capitalized).

Answer (score 12):

Putting your preamble in a `.sty` file, and changing `\usepackage` statements to `RequirePackage`, and closing off the file with `\endinput` is the most straightforward way.

It is important to realize that in a style file `@` is a letter, meaning that it can be used in commands. So if you have code in your preamble between a `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` pair, you can leave out these two commands in the `.sty` file.

Now, if you want to go a step further, you can specify what format is needed, a name and description of the package using `\NeedsTeXFormat` and `\ProvidesPackage`. Furthermore, you can define package options and process them using `\DeclareOption` and `\ProcessOptions`, but if you go that far, either learn from looking in well-made `.sty` files on CTAN or have a look at [LaTeX2e for class and package writers](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf).

Comment: Is the `\endinput` actually required?

Comment: I don't think it is required, but have been told it is good practice.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to put it into a `.sty` file, and then having the other people simply include it. Admittedly, this is a bit of a hack, and you can be more sophisticated with it.

I recommend you look at another style file to kind of see the layout, like how to declare the package, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I use a different approach other than a style file. I use `Autohotkey`, a small little hotkey expander. Every time I type ´std#` in **any** IDE, it gets expanded to

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

The software can do much more, e.g. inserting (calculated) dates in different formats or moving the cursor after expansion. The definition file is in my dropbox so changes go to all my machines more or less immediately.