# Is there a source function/capability in LaTeX

Tags: packages, preamble

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a standard preamble into a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77/how-to-make-a-standard-preamble-into-a-package)

I often have the same preamble stuff in my documents that kind of clutter the work space a bit.  Some are custom commands I've stolen from here or there and some are calls to packages.

In R I can use a function called `source` that allows me to create an external file of these commands and then I can just call `source` to read this external file and it's magically in the working memory ([LINK to source info](http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/base/html/source.html)).  It would be nice to do the same with LaTeX.  Does LaTeX have this kind of capability?

Comment: Related: [How to make a standard preamble into a package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77/how-to-make-a-standard-preamble-into-a-package)

Comment: @hpesoj626  I think you're right.  It's actually a duplicate and this thread should probably be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three ways to outsource your preamble:

1. *(The easiest one)* Separate `.tex` file, say `preamble.tex`. Usage:

   ```
   \input{preamble} % NOT \include and NO file ending!
   \begin{document}
   …
   ```

   where `preamble.tex` consists of the usual:

   ```
   \documentclass[<options>]{class}
   \usepackage[…]{…}
   \usepackage[…]{…}
   \usepackage[…]{…}
   % own settings, stuff, etc.
   ```
2. Custom class (`.cls`) or package (`.sty`) file. Usage:

   ```
   \documentclass[<options>]{myclass}
   \usepackage[<options>]{mypackage}
   \usepackage{other packages, only for this document}
   \begin{document}
   …
   ```

   Your custom package can be simply just the same as the aforementioned `preamble.tex` (but with `.sty`), but you can also write a package that is quite dynamic, see for example: [Reference guide to begin writing a class and/or a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2416/reference-guide-to-begin-writing-a-class-and-or-a-package)
3. Pre-compiled preamble

   - [Precompiled preamble  for LaTeX](http://magic.aladdin.cs.cmu.edu/2007/11/02/precompiled-preamble-for-latex/)
   - [`mylatexformat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mylatexformat)
   - [Custom format file: How to automate the generation of the "precompiled preamble" whenever one of the files that are used there are changed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49388/custom-format-file-how-to-automate-the-generation-of-the-precompiled-preamble)
   - [ultrafast pdflatex with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling)

Comment: I will add some resourceful links in a minute …

Comment: In case you are looking for links for 3: [ultrafast pdflatex with precompiling](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79493/ultrafast-pdflatex-with-precompiling) [Custom format file: How to automate the generation of the “precompiled preamble” whenever one of the files that are used there are changed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49388/custom-format-file-how-to-automate-the-generation-of-the-precompiled-preamble).  I am working on a problem I am having with this so had the link open.

Comment: @TylerRinker Yes, the first one is quite the easiest way as it is just a literally way of out-sourcing your code. No much experience needed. For the other ways I refer to the full knowledge of TeX.SE, all is already covered. (The third way is a very experienced one and is only if at all needed for very big documents (or slow machines).)