# ProvidesPackage and usepackage

Tags: macros, packages

I have seen papers containing a command `\ProvidesPackage`. Is it different than `\usepackage`?

What is the difference between `\ProvidesPackage` and `\usepackage`?

Comment: `\ProvidesPackage` defines a package, which you can use with `\usepackage`. Or is it `\RequirePackage` that you remember?

Comment: Are you meaning `\RequirePackage`, rather than `\ProvidesPackage`?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/77/how-to-make-a-standard-preamble-into-a-package

Comment: Providing an air ambulance service is not the same as using one....

Answer (score 9):

The most commonly known command to use extra functionality is called `\usepackage{<name>}`, which if we say out loud reveals what it does: It uses a package called `<name>`. it is important to know that `\usepackage` can only be used in the document preamble, that is the part between `\documentclass` and the beginning of typesetting at `\begin{document}`.

Sometimes we want to do stuff before loading any class, for example by setting different options. The command here is called `\RequirePackage{<name>}`. Actually it does just the same as `\usepackage`, or rather vice versa.

---

When loading a package, LaTeX checks some details, for example the date. The only way this is possible, is a short introduction that the package gives to LaTeX. "*I, the file, provide package `<name>` dating of 2015/06/13*"

```
\ProvidesPackage{<name>}[2015/06/13 package <name>]
```