# Using \newcommand to create \faculty \department etc. doesn't work

Tags: macros

I tried to use `\newcommand{\faculty}[1]{\gdef\@faculty{#1}}` to have others use my template for thesis and just change text in the brackets `\faculty{Fakulta strojní}` and it changes every faculty name in the document, e.g. in titlepage. It does work until I add more commands, like `\department` etc. Then it tells me `Use of \@ doesn't match its definition.` and shows *Faculty* without F. I am using `subfiles` package and `preamble.tex`.

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
        \large\textsc{{VŠB - Technická univerzita Ostrava\\
        \@faculty\\
        \@department}}
        
        \vfill
        
        {\LARGE{\sffamily{\textbf{Název práce}\\
        Title name}}}\\
        
        \vfill
        \normalsize{
        \begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{XX}
        Autor: & autor\\
        Vedoucí disertační práce: & director
    \end{tabularx}\\
        \vspace{2em}
    Ostrava~2021}\
\end{titlepage}
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\input{nastaveni/preamble}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{subfiles}
    \externaldocument[M-]{\subfix{main}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\faculty{Fakulta strojní}
\department{Katedra energetiky}

\begin{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't you need to put `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`?

Comment: unrelated but size commands do not take an argument so `\normalsize{..}` should be `\normalsize ...`, `\LARGE{..}` should be `\LARGE ...` etc

Comment: @JairoA.delRio Where exactly?:)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle deleted brackets, no change...

Comment: @JanOpletal yes exactly: they are doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using commands that involve `@` which is a reserved character for use within class and package files. Since you are using `\input` to input the commands instead of putting them into a proper package, then you need to wrap the `\input` command with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\input{nastaveni/preamble}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{subfiles}
    \externaldocument[M-]{\subfix{main}}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\faculty{Fakulta strojní}
\department{Katedra energetiky}

\begin{document}
```

See the following questions for more details:

- [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/2693)
- [How to make a standard preamble into a package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/77/2693)

Comment: When I added that it changed to this: it prints `faculty` and `department` but not `Fakulta strojní` and `Katedra energetiky` as it was meant.

Comment: @JanOpletal: Did you place the `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair *outside* of the `titlepage` environment, or *inside*?

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake when using titlepage as `subfile` and not printing by `\maketitle`, and defining titlepage in preamble. Now it works :)